# How to use date picker with form_for in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm new to rails,Any clues ?  and it would be better if you can suggest me what to read as well.

Im adding a date picker plugin into an existing rails4 app. i found [this plugin](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails) on Github. i followed the instruction and configured everything in my app. Visiting **http://localhost:3000/bookings/new** looks fine, but after i fill up the information and submit it , error occurs :

```
ArgumentError in BookingsController#create
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

booking_controller.rb:

```
def new
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  def create
    @booking = current_user.bookings.build(booking_params)    # Not the final implementation!
    if @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "You have submited the information successfully!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

new.html.rb

```
    <%= form_for (@booking) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/errorbooking_messages' %>
      <%= f.label :date_of_tour %>
      <input data-provide="datepicker">

      <%= f.label :hotel_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :hotel_name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :hotel_address %>
      <%= f.text_field :hotel_address, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: You want jquery date picker or dropdown of year, month and date?

Comment: In your `create` action, try `@booking = Booking.new(booking_params)`. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: @user123 the one i implemented is a date picker, I'm able to pick the date and year, it looks fine on the page, not after i submit the information .

Comment: @Zoran Hi, i have a user model associated with booking model . That's why i implemented in that way. And actually , it works fine without date picker , not after i add the date picker on .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Replace this input field

```
<input data-provide="datepicker">
```

by

```
<%= f.text_field :date_of_tour, "data-provide" => 'datepicker' %>
```

Hope it's helpful.

Just to build on this answer. As of rails 4 you can also use the following format.

```
<%= f.text_field :date_of_tour, data:{ provide:'datepicker' } %>
```

Comment: Your welcome, this 2 links you can refer.

https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: i have come across this one, what i have encountered here is probably about lacking the knowledge of writing code for views in rails. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Using data hash is also an option `:data => { :provide => :datepicker }`